# Как получить переменную из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

В питоне есть **if a in b:** а существует ли **a = a in b?**, чтобы получить сам **текст** из переменной...
Мой код:

```
msg.content = "Привет"
strings = ['Привет друг!', 'Как дела?', 'Что делаешь?']

if msg.content in strings:
    text = msg.content in strings #text должен быть текстом, например Привет друг!
    per = fuzz.ratio(text , msg.content)
    if per > 50: # если похоже, бот будет отвечать этим сообщением.
        return
```

Comment: Что значит "чтобы получить сам текст из переменной"? Если a внутри b есть, то a уже содержит текст, который есть внутри переменной b. Сама по себе конструкция `a = a in b` синтаксически корректна, но в `a` запишется результат проверки (`True` или `False`)

Comment: Как получить сам текст из списка переменной?

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы хотите сказать. Приведите в вопросе пример списка, пример переменной, и пример того, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Вот мой код:

    if msg.content in strings:
        text = strings in msg.content
        per = fuzz.ratio(text , msg.content)
        print(per)


Мне нужно получить текст, что-бы сделать сравнение.

Comment: Добавьте пример в сам вопрос, для этого нажмите "править" под ним. Комментарии не предназначены для блоков кода.

Comment: добавил код, который вы просили.

Comment: Все равно не понятно, что вы хотите в итоге получить. Приведите пример на конкретных данных (конкретный список, конкретная строка, конкретный результат).

Comment: добавил код, который вы просили.

Comment: Если в `msg.content` лежит "а", и нужно получить "а", тогда просто `text = msg.content` вместо `text = strings in msg.content`

Comment: Тогда нечего будет сравнять, вместо того текста может быть фраза, и мне нужно сравнить на сколько она похожа.

Comment: Тогда приведите пример с фразой, а не с буквами. И опять же, с полным описанием - что у вас в списке, что может быть в msg.content, что должно в итоге получиться.

Comment: Сделал как вы и просили.

Comment: Чтобы у вас условие выполнилось, в msg.content может быть например "Привет друг!", и тогда чтобы в text оказалось "Привет друг!", то нужно выполнить присваивание `text = msg.content`. В итоге у вас сравнение всегда будет давать 100% совпадение строк, и от него не будет никакого толка. Поэтому и нужно понимать, что у вас на входе в msg.content, и что должно быть на выходе.

Comment: Похоже, этот вопрос невозможно решить.

Comment: Вопрос можно решить, просто вы не делаете то что я прошу сделать) Скорее всего вам нужно циклом пройти по списку, с каждым элементом списка через `fuzz.ratio` сравнивать `msg.content`, там где совпало больше какого-то порога - что-то делать.

Comment: Я так и хочу сделать.

Comment: Ну собственно я и написал как делать. Точное сравнение через `msg.content in strings` тогда и не нужно, нужен цикл и сравнение через `fuzz.ratio`.